# i can't align material design cards in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

i have used ng-flex so they are responsive. but I want to align them so that they are all the same height.
[how you can see they aren't alinged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJEny.jpg).

```css
.content {
    padding: 16px;
 }

.content > mat-card {
    width: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="content">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
<div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.sm="33%" *ngFor="let manga of mangaList">
  <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4" >
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{ manga.title }}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <img mat-card-image src="{{ manga.preview }}">
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-button>Leggi</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="updateBookmark(manga)">
        <i *ngIf="manga.bookmarked == 'false'; else ifBookmarked" class="fa fa-bookmark-o fa-lg"></i>
        <ng-template #ifBookmarked>
          <i class="fa fa-bookmark fa-lg"></i>
        </ng-template>
      </button> 
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the card class itself a limit with maxheight + height . So all cards same height.
If you want the contents of the card to have all same height you have to hardcode the height for mat-card-header, the image and mat-card-actions. To regulate the image height container make a div arround it. Something like that:

```html
<div fxLayout="row grid">
     <mat-card *ngFor="let manga of mangaList">
        <mat-card-header>
          -- Content --
        </mat-card-header>
        <div>
          <img>
        </div>
        <mat-card-actions>
          -- Content --
        </mat-card-actions>
     </mat-card>
</div>
```

```css
Card {
  height: 200px;
  max-height 200px;

   mat-card-header {
     height 20px;
     max-height 20px;
   }

   image-div {
    height 60px;
    max-height 60px;
   }

   mat-card-actions {
    height 20px;
    max-height 20px;
   }
}
```

Also i see on the 3rd one is the Title to long. If you wanna keep the Title length you gotta adjust  height

Comment: thank you, it works.. i have just to fix 
the height of the images